# Unsupported operation leading to lease error in pyvmomi

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

I am trying to deploy OVF to vSphere 5.5 by a python script using `pyvmomi` due to an error `The operation is not supported on the object`. The deepest I could get into this error was by printing `ImportVApp.error` which has this output.

```
(vmodl.fault.NotSupported) {
   dynamicType = <unset>,
   dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
   msg = 'The operation is not supported on the object.',
   faultCause = <unset>,
   faultMessage = (vmodl.LocalizableMessage) []
}
```

The lease is giving my error after initialising and giving the error above. You can find my script [here](https://gist.github.com/goindwalia/48a5f9ab6a2f4eedfdba).

Answer (score 1):

When I came across this error, it was because I needed to connect directly to the individual host IP and not the Vcenter IP.  Also I would like to add that there were permissions that the user I was using did not have permissions to deploy an ovf directly on that host.  I tested this with the root user and it worked so I needed to upgrade my permissions to do so. Hope this helps anyone else out there.